# Java like Window Navigation in WPF

Tags: wpf, navigation, jpanel, jwindow

I am a Java developer, and for user interaction I create a universal `JFrame` and has a `JPanel` container in it, and I swap that container with the other panels I created.

I started to develop WPF applications but I cannot find how this can be done. All I found that there are `Page` and `UserControl` but I could not understand the difference and how my task can be achieved. I cannot find good tutorials and I cannot understand how to search it in Google.

Any good info or tutorial would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @svick I do not want to open a new Windows each time I want to show a thing. So I want a main windows that has a container, and that container changes over the time, but I do not know how to search it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ContentControl` for that purpose. You can set its `Content` property to any other control and it will show where the `ContentControl` is placed.

Alternatively, you can use [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and set the `Content` to a ViewModel, while providing a view in a `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I meant. I created `UserControl` and edited it via graphical interface, and I am happy.