# switching xaml pages in a wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was just wondering how to go about switching xaml "pages" in an application. I google, and google, and google, but I either cant figure out what the people are talking about, or it is for silverlight or what ever.

Basically what I want is an application, which has a main window in it, and when A user clicks a link (home for example), the inside of the window displays the home screen. Then the user clicks the login link, and the login screen appears.

I assume that I will need to use c# to do this (which is ok, I am used to using c#, I am just using xaml so that I have more control over what my forms look like). Some of the solutions I have read, seem to be doing wierd stuff in xaml that I really dont understand...

From what I have read, some people say to use windows, some say to use pages...which do you recommend for someone just starting to learn xaml.

I use expression blend, and visual studio 2010 to do this work.

I am new to Xaml, but have lots of experience with C#.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java like Window Navigation in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562688/java-like-window-navigation-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into the MVVM design pattern for WPF and using that.

You would have something like a `ShellViewModel` which contains your application shell. This contains a `CurrentPage` property, which is the ViewModel of whatever page is current. When someone clicks a link, the `CurrentPage` property gets updated to whatever ViewModel should be displayed.

I actually wrote something about it [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/) if you're interested